# Postlinear gravitational wave generation by Thorne et. al

Tags: general-relativity, research-level, gravitational-waves, perturbation-theory

My question is related to this [paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1975ApJ...200..245T). In this paper, Thorne and Kovacs considered the so-called postlinear gravitational wave formalism. Basically, you want to take into account the influence of the perturbed metric on the motion of matter. The equations of motion are equations (10a, 10b). These two equations can be expanded in the series of $\epsilon$ which is the typical value of the perturbed inverse metric $\bar h^{\mu\nu}$ *inside* of the source. The expansions are equations (9).

In Section IV., they started to consider the so-called postlinear gravitational wave generation formalism. Equations (23) and (24) are the ones they used to calculate the gravitational wave. Equations (23) seem OK, because they are expanded upto the order of $\epsilon$, but I do not quite understand equations (24).

For example, the left hand side of equation (24a) is of the 2nd order in $\epsilon$, while the right hand side is of the 3rd order! How come they are equal to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add orders, so you can't say that the right-hand side is 3rd order.  In particular, the notation ${}_1\Gamma$ is saying that this quantity is *only accurate to* first order in $\epsilon$; not that it is *proportional to* $\epsilon^1$.  It is that second (wrong) interpretation that would allow you to add orders.  Instead, you need to consider contributions to error, which is more of a min/max operation than a multiplication.  In fact, this is the whole point of the discussion below their Eq. (13a) — that fractional errors in $\bar{h}^{\mu \nu}$ (and hence in ${\Gamma^\mu}_{\alpha \nu})$ produce higher-order errors in $T^{\mu\nu}$.  This is their reason for introducing the two separate numbers $n_h$ and $n_T$.

Incidentally, if you are new to this subject, this paper might not be the best place to start.  Thorne's [1980 review article](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.52.299) is a much better and more pedagogical approach.  You might also be interested in Blanchet's (free) [living review](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2014-2/), which discusses related approximations in great detail, as applied to the case of compact binaries, and is presented in a much more modern form.

Comment: Thank you, @Mike. I might misunderstand their paper. Let me read the two articles, first.